# String alignment does not work with ansi colors

Tags: python, text, printing, colors, format

Facing this issue with Python:

```
a = "text"
print('{0:>10}'.format(a))
# output:      text
b = "\x1b[33mtext\x1b[0m"
print('{0:>10}'.format(b))
# output: text
```

As you can see the right-justification stopped working once the coloring tags get added to the text. The second "text" should be indented as the first one, but it was not.

Comment: Interesting. Can confirm this doesn't work with f-strings either: `print(f"{b:>10}")`, so at least it's *consistent*

Comment: Aha, note, `len(b)` is 13... makes sense I guess

Comment: Juanpa, you are right, that is the reason. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: Can you remove my account?

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999/233625) for details of now to delete your account

Comment: Thank you Greg! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to be expected because the data is already longer than your field width:

```
>>> len(b)
13
>>> len('{0:>10}'.format(b))
13
```

To see a workaround, check here:  [Printed length of a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14889454/674039) (in particular, [the answer from user dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14889588/674039))

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and I came up with a solution:

My problem was:

```py
lst = ['A','B','\033[94mC\033[0m']
print(f"|{lst[0]:^9}|{lst[1]:^9}|{lst[2]:^9}|")
```

It didn't work. So I had to separate the 'big word' in strings:

```py
str1 = '\033[94m'
str2 = '\033[0m'
lst = ['A','B','C']
print(f"|{lst[0]:^9}|{lst[1]:^9}|{str1}{lst[2]:^9}{str2}|")
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Nice workaround, but the root cause is still the accepted answer :)